# Bootstrap modal - remote-data url

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a button generated using php, that calls a bootstrap modal :

```
echo '<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-modal" data-remote="printlist.php?type=rangeddetail&pid='.$pid.'&startdate='.$startdate.'&enddate='.$enddate.'&storeformat='.$storeformat.'&retailer='.$retailer.'">'.$ranged_v.'</a>'
```

The data-remote property ends up like this when rendered in the html:

```
data-remote="printlist.php?type=rangeddetail&pid=xxx&startdate=2016-07-05&enddate=2016-07-12&storeformat='x 1','x2','x3','x 4','x5'&retailer='r x'"
```

This brings an error when the button is pressed :

```
jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 1','x2','x3','x 4','x5'&retailer='r x'
```

How can I make this right?

Comment: in php use str_replace("\'", "", $storeformat) and str_replace("\'", "", $retailer)

Comment: why you give space between x and 4, it may come like this 'x4' or show your script

Comment: the storeformat and retailer comes from an array from an ajax call from mysql in the form of comma seperated values. there are some values that are 2 words with spaces or even 3 words with spaces

Answer (score 0):

I found it, looks like I had to wrap the variables that are causing the problems with urlencode :

```
'printlist.php?type=rangeddetail&pid='.$pid.'&startdate='.$startdate.'&enddate='.$enddate.'&storeformat='.urlencode($storeformat).'&retailer='.urlencode($retailer);
```